# Is there a sexier alternative to the status bar in Safari?

Tags: safari, ios

I hate the status bar. However, I love hovering over URLs to find out where they will take me. Is there an alternative to having the status bar on at all times, or constantly toggling on/off? An extension, or maybe a preference that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like the free [UltimateStatusBar](http://ultimatestatusbar.com/) extension.

Visible only when you're hovering over a link, it shows where things lead, but does other stuff too. Like shortener expansion and favicon previews.

It's got lots of built-in themes you can use to customize the appearance.

Comment: Holy crap that's awesome! A ton of really cool features too. Only question - why isn't it in the Safari Extensions gallery on Apple's site?

Comment: @bpapa Apple requires that you submit your extension for approval for that gallery. The developer may not have submitted it, or Apple may have rejected it (who knows why).

Comment: It actually is in the gallery, I just didn't notice at the time. False alarm! This is a great extension.